# Is it possible to have a bool/string/int/etc that can be accessed by any form in the program?

Tags: c#, variables

I've done some research on global variables, and have come up with the fact that static variables should be able to solve my problem. I don't understand how to make these, though. How would I do so? Also, if static variables would not solve my problem, what should I use?

I want to be able to access a string, bool and int in my main form, from another form. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables (or better yet, properties) would likely work.  You would declare this as:

```
// In Form1 (could be internal or public)
public static bool SomeBool { get; set; }
```

And then, to access, you'd use `Form1.SomeBool = true;` or `if (Form1.SomeBool) {`, etc.

That being said, "global" data like this is discouraged for a reason - there is typically some better way to handle this.  For example, you might want to make a custom class that holds your data, and pass a reference to an instance of this class to the new form when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only static, it must be `public static`.  You can simply declare it like any other variable, as in `public static int x = 1;`. Then you can acces it like `ClassFoo.x`, but you must be in a static context as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this information to be held per form instance (an object) then you don't want to use static fields. On the other hand if what you want is to have some information that you can access from any instance (it is shared) of your class form, or in other words, you want to have this information only once... then yes, use static fields.

What you would want to do is something like this:

```
//partial because I take you are using a form designer.
//and also because the class is gonna have more things than those showed here.
//in particular the example call a method "UseFields" that I did not define.
public partial class MyForm: form
{
    private static bool boolField;
    private static string stringField;
    private static int intField;

    private void Method()
    {
         //Do something with the fields
         UseFields(boolField, stringField, intField);
         UseFields(IsBoolFieldSet, SomeString, SharedInformation.SomeInt);
    }

    //You can also wrap them in a property:
    public static bool IsBoolFieldSet
    {
        get
        {
            return boolField;
        }
        //Don't put a set if you want it to be read only
        set
        {
            return boolField;
        }
    }

    //Or declare an static property like so:
    public static string SomeString { get; set; }
}

//Another good option is to have this information in a separate class
public class SharedInformation
{
    public static int SomeInt { get; set; }        
}
```

Please take care with shared state, in particular in a multithreaded enviroment, because this information may be changed without notice by another object that also has access.